# How to define a varying exponential function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

A function which converts a value (x) in an positive exponential rate, and when reaching a certain point (y value), turns into negative exponential until it becomes constant.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufnRS.png)

The ideal would be something like the one embedded. How is it called, and how can I equate it like I do with quadratic functions in ax^2 + bx + c?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that what you are looking for is the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).